# Multiple slideshows on the same page

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am having trouble running more then one slideshow on one page. I am trying to make due with the code i was given (which i know is out dated). My first problem was the use of multiple functions with the same name, i solved that problem by embedding the functions into other functions to distinguish between them (ex: show1() show2()). Here is what i have so far, im not sure what is the problem now as it could be multiple things and my lack of javascript knowledge. Any help would be great thank you!

```
<!-- The following script is for the rotating images for the banner ad in right column            -->
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Beginning of JavaScript -

if (document.images) {
ads = new Array(5);
ads[0] = "./images/okuma.jpg";
ads[1] = "./images/schlumberger.gif";
ads[2] = "./images/uesystems_logo.jpg";
ads[3] = "./images/brady.jpg";
ads[4] = "./images/ats.png";
}

newplace = new Array(5);
newplace[0] = "http://www.okuma.com/home.html" 
newplace[1] = "http://www.slb.com/"
newplace[2] = "http://www.uesystems.com/"
newplace[3] = "http://www.bradyid.com/bradyid/cms/contentView.do/6974/Visual-     Workplace.html"
newplace[4] = "http://www.advancedtech.com/"


var timer = null
var counter = 0

function banner() {
        timer=setTimeout("ban()", 6000);
        counter++;
        if (counter >= 5)
        counter = 0;
        document.bannerad1.src = ads[counter];
}

function show1(){
function gothere() {
        counter2 = counter;
        window.open(newplace[counter2]);
}
}
// - End of JavaScript - -->

</script>

<!-- The following script is for the rotating images for the banner ad in right column(2)  -->
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Beginning of JavaScript -

if (document.images) {
ads = new Array(4);
ads[0] = "./marcon/images/arms_reliability_logo.jpg";
ads[1] = "./marcon/images/brunson_logo.jpg";
ads[2] = "./marcon/images/ctc_logo.jpg";
ads[3] = "./marcon/images/descase_logo.jpg";
}

newplace = new Array(4);
newplace[0] = "http://www.globalreliability.com/home" 
newplace[1] = "http://www.brunson.us"
newplace[2] = "http://www.ctconline.com/_home.aspx"
newplace[3] = "http://www.des-case.com"



var timer = null
var counter = 0

function banner() {
        timer=setTimeout("banner()", 6000);
        counter++;
        if (counter >= 4)
        counter = 0;
        document.bannerad2.src = ads[counter];
}
function show2(){
function gothere() {
        counter2 = counter;
        window.open(newplace[counter2]);
}
}
// - End of JavaScript - -->

</script>
```

and

```
    <p align="center"><font size="2"><b>Companies Supporting<br />R&M Research:</b><br  />     (click logo for company info)</font></p>
        <p align="center"><a href="javascript:show1()"><IMG   SRC="./images/schlumberger.gif" WIDTH="180" HIGHT="200" BORDER="0" NAME="bannerad1"></a>
</p>
       <br />

            <hr noshade="noshade" size="0" color="#4c617e" />
 <br />

        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b>Thank you to the following for<br />their MARCON '12 support</b><br />(click logo for company info)</font></p>
        <p align="center"><a href="javascript:show2()"><IMG  SRC="./marcon/images/arms_reliability_logo.jpg" WIDTH="180" HIGHT="200" BORDER="0"   NAME="bannerad2"></a>
```

Comment: You've got global variables overriding global variables all over the place.. timer, counter, ads, newplace, banner().  You would have to change all those too.  (On a side note, if possible I would ditch this code and find a better example online.  A jquery slideshow plugin perhaps?)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this working example.  Hopefully you can pick up a little javascript knowledge by studying it a bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/RRjGP/3/

Comment: For some reason i cant get that example to work, is there anything im missing?

Comment: well the image paths go nowhere of course.  But you can use developer tools or firebug to inspect it and see that the image source and the wrapping href are indeed changing.

Comment: See i tried to use the same code but with one modification and i still can not get it to work on the site. The site that i am doing this for has the sloppiest organization i have seen so i can not tell if something is wrong with my code or if there is something else i am over looking.

This is what i changed

 window.onload=function() {
  slideShow(ads1, newplace1, document.bannerad1);
  slideShow(ads2, newplace2, document.bannerad2);
  slideShow(ads3, newplace3, document.bannerad3);
}